# eloquent javascript 5.2 mother-child

Tags: javascript

I have a problem because my code returns different result than the solution code. I found out that the difference is in filter function.

Link to excersise : http://eloquentjavascript.net/code/#5.2

my filtering function:

```
ancestry.filter(function(p) { return p.mother != null; })
```

returns 33 results while filtering function from solution returns only 17:

```
ancestry.filter(function(person) { return byName[person.mother] != null;})
```

Which one is correct? and WHY 2nd function returns different results?

**2nd Question:**

I don't know how to pull mothers born date for mapping function.

```
function ageDiff(p) { return p.born - p.mother.born } //p.mother.born doesn't work
```

Thanks, KK

Comment: Unrelated to what you're asking, `return (p.mother != null) ? true : false;` can be simplified to just `return (p.mother != null)`.

Comment: thanks :) Code updated.

Comment: _"WHY 2nd function returns different results?"_ Because `p.mother != null` is not the same as `byName[person.mother] != null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get different results is because you're not testing the same thing.

Not shown in your question is this code:

```
var byName = {};
ancestry.forEach(function(person) {
  byName[person.name] = person;
});
```

...which populates the `byName` object with a property for every person in the array such that you can look up that person with `byName["person's name here"]`.

So with that in mind, your code:

```
ancestry.filter(function(p) { return p.mother != null; })
```

...says to filter the `ancestry` array and keep only elements that have a `mother` property that is not null.

The official answer code:

```
ancestry.filter(function(person) { return byName[person.mother] != null;})
```

...says to filter the `ancestry` array and keep elements for which the specified `.mother` exists within the `byName` object. That is to say, those elements where the specified mother was in the `ancestry` array herself - not all are: Emma de Milliano is an example of a person whose mother is not null but also doesn't have her own entry in the array. (The fact that it is testing `!= null` is a bit misleading, because in fact `byName` has no properties with a `null` value: what the `!= null` test really does in this case is test `!= undefined`, because the `!=` operator considers `null` and `undefined` to be equal.)

> ***I don't know how to pull mothers born date for mapping function.***

The mother's details can be found by retrieving her record from the `byName` object with `byName[p.mother]`.